# How to check SSL Kafka topic is authorized using keystore

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka

I have a simple [KafkaProducer](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html) to produced into SSL Kafka topic using `keystore.jks` file

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 0);
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
props.put("ssl.key.password", "password");
props.put("ssl.keystore.password", "password");
props.put("ssl.keystore.location", "/keystore.jks");

Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-topic", key, body));
```

But since `KafkaProducer` is a lazy instance and which creates a connection with a Kafka cluster on the arrival of the first message causing failure at runtime if the topic is unauthorized

**Error:**

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [my-topic]

Is there a way to check topic authorization either using [KafkaAdminClient](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/KafkaAdminClient.html) or writing custom logic before starting KafkaProducer? I do have below code extracting certs & key from `keystore` file but couldn't find any next steps

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());  
char[] pwdArray = "password".toCharArray();
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("/keystore.jks"), pwdArray);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you did not configure the necessary properties to [trust](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_configclients) the Kafka server:

```
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
```

probably your SSL setup is fine although, as you indicated, there is some kind of problem related with the authorization of your client:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [my-topic]

Please, consider review the [Kafka authorization documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz), especially the [part](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz_ssl) that describes how the user name is derived from the `CN` of your client SSL certificate:

> By default, the SSL user name will be of the form "CN=writeuser,OU=Unknown,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown". One can change that by setting ssl.principal.mapping.rules to a customized rule in server.properties. This config allows a list of rules for mapping X.500 distinguished name to short name.

Once the user is identified, check that the necessary ACLs are applied for him and the topic `my-topic`. Please, see the provided [examples](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz_examples) in the documentation.

For example, to add the above-mentioned user as a producer of the topic `my-topic` try something similar to:

```sh
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:writeuser --producer --topic my-topic
```

You can verify the ACLs applied to a resource, `my-topic` in your use case, with something like:

```sh
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --list --topic my-topic
```

Comment: Thanks for the command line answer, but I'm looking for Java code to do the validation before connecting to the Kafka topic

Comment: You are welcome @Deadpool. Honestly, I haven't used the administration related code of the Kafka Java API before. I was reviewing the API and related documentation and I was trying to complete my answer in order to provide a Java based solution based as well when I realized your comment and that you actually provided a new answer. You are completely right, this is the right solution. In any way, please, consider review this [project](https://github.com/nbogojevic/kafka-operator/blob/master/src/main/java/nb/kafka/operator/AclManager.java). See next comment

Comment: And [this other one](https://github.com/kafka-ops/kafka-topology-builder/blob/master/src/test/java/com/purbon/kafka/topology/AccessControlManagerTest.java). In my research I came across then and I think they could be helpful.

Comment: But to be honest your answer helped me to find the path for solution @jccampanero

Comment: Thank you very much for marking my answer as correct @Deadpool, I really appreciate it!!. Please do not hesitate to contact me if you think I can be of any help, I will be glad to try to help you. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

After long research and with the help of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66155207/9959152) provided by @jccampanero, I have created a block of java code to list ACLS using [AdminClient](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html) for a specific topic

```
AdminClient adminClient = KafkaAdminClient.create(configProps);

ResourcePatternFilter resourceFilter = new ResourcePatternFilter(ResourceType.TOPIC,"my-topic", PatternType.ANY);

AclBindingFilter aclBindingFilter = new AclBindingFilter(resourceFilter, AccessControlEntryFilter.ANY);

DescribeAclsResult describe = adminClient.describeAcls(aclBindingFilter);

KafkaFuture<Collection<AclBinding>> values = describe.values();

Collection<AclBinding> aclBindings = values.get();

aclBindings.forEach(acl->{
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s %s",acl.entry().operation().name(),acl.entry().principal(),acl.entry().permissionType().name()));
    });
```

**Output:**

```
DESCRIBE User:CN=test-cert.com,O=Corporation,OU=1234567,L=Newyork,ST=NY,C=US ALLOW
WRITE User:CN=CN=test-cert.com,O=Corporation,OU=1234567,L=Newyork,ST=NY,C=US ALLOW
READ User:CN=test-cert.com,O=Corporation,OU=1234567,L=Newyork,ST=NY,C=US ALLOW
```

Now you can extract the `CN` part from `AclBinding` and then use it as `alias` to get the `Certificate` from JSK file

```
 KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
 char[] pwdArray = "password".toCharArray();
 keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("/keystore.jks"), pwdArray);
       
 Certificate certificate = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);  //alias = test-cert.com
  if (certificate instanceof X509Certificate) {
      X509Certificate x509cert = (X509Certificate) certificate;

          // Get subject
          Principal principal = x509cert.getSubjectDN();
          String subjectDn = principal.getName();
          System.out.println(principal);  //test-cert.com

       }
```